# Harmonical analysis of Fm D♭ E♭ B♭

Tags: chords, harmony, chord-progressions, analysis

How should I analyse this chord progression: Fm D♭ E♭ B♭ ?

Is it (in A♭ major): vi IV V  II ?

Comment: Assuming there are no key changes, a very basic rule is to look at the last chord of a piece to figure out what key you are in. Most pieces end on I or i. There are ones that end on V or IV, but those are usually really obvious, as they sound incomplete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is unlikely that this is Ab major because the progression doesn't have an Ab major in it and also doesn't typically have a Bb chord. If it has a Bb chord it is usually followed by a Eb chord as the Bb chord will [function as a secondary dominant](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15918/differentiating-between-ii-and-ii7-secondary-dominant-v-of-v) in the key of Ab major not II.

I see it as a progression in F minor as a `i VI VII IV`. The IV is technically not from F minor, but could have easily been taken from the relative major. Another possibility I see is the chord progression being in Eb major as a `ii bVII I V`.

Without seeing more of the piece, I would lean towards Eb major or F minor over Ab major.

Comment: B♭ is more likely to be found in the minor scale as a foreign IV than as a foreign II in the major scale?

Comment: I play this exact chord progression in F minor frequently. It has F as a strong tonal center in my experience.

Comment: I would tend to agree with the F minor interpretation (i bVII bVII IV), with the major IV probably coming from F Dorian scale (or Ionain/relative major scale, as previously noted). Although as mentioned, Eb also works.

Comment: Yeah, an actual II chord is rather rare. It's usually actually a V/V, which is almost always followed by a dominant chord (e.g. V, vii°) in close succession.

Answer (score 1):

E flat major. That is the key that the passage resolves to, as you can hear by playing an E flat major chord after the B flat chord. If you follow the B flat with any of the other chords, the passage is left sounding unresolved.

Hence, the chord progression is ii,flattened VII, I, V